# How do I match one column to be equal to another column minus one using Unix?

Tags: awk, sed

I'm not sure if I should use an awk command or sed?

I have been trying

```
awk '{ print $2 == $3 }'
```

first time doing code!

Comment: Yes, awk will be easier for this task, and assuming your problems are grow in that direction, you want to spend your time learning awk. But you haven't given us much to help on. It is almost always best to include 1) small set of sample input, 2) required output from that same input 3) current code, output and exact texts of error messages. Please add some details and readers will help. Also, unless you're really using an old Unix OS, you're better  off to use the linux tag and tags for the tools you are interested in (but only 1 programming language, or some people will get mad at you (-;!) .

Comment: Also, putting your primary question in the heading should be avoided, unless it is 6 words or less (as a rule-of-thumb). That heading should be in the body of your question and something shorter as a subject. *"Comparing columns in Unix"* might be a better headline. ....  It really helps for readers to **see** your problem with actual data. So please edit your Q and supply some more background info. Good luck!

Comment: Since you know that `$3` is the value of the 3rd column, I think without knowing anything else about AWK you could have guessed that `$3-1` would be the value of the 3rd column minus 1. Don't be afraid to guess and try things like `awk '{ print $3-1 }'` to see if you're right. Do get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn about AWK though.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially,

```
awk '$2 == $3-1' file
```

Your attempt lacks the subtraction, and prints something for every line.

In very brief, the general syntax of an Awk script is a sequence of

*condition* `{` *actions* `}`

pairs, where both are optional.  If *condition* is missing, Awk performs the *actions* unconditionally. If `{` *actions* `}` is missing, the default action is to print the current input record (by default, input records are individual lines from the input file or stream).

In your attempt, you would `print $2 == $3` unconditionally, which evaluates `$2 == $3`, which can be either true or false, and prints that result.

In the fixed script, the *condition* is `$2 == $3-1` and the default action is to print the line; so we print only when the *condition* is true.

This short abridged explanation only summarizes what you will find in any basic Awk tutorial. The [Stack Overflow `awk` tag info page](/tags/awk/info) has some more information, including links to learning resources.

`sed` has no support for arithmetic, so is unsuitable for this task. (That is not to say it cannot be done, just that a `sed` solution would have to reimplement subtraction using `sed` primitives. Some people enjoy that sort of challenge, but it is not suitable for a beginner.)